# Multiple lines on a button

Tags: android, android-button

List item

I want to create a button with one image and more than 2 lines of text. Is it possible in XML? (eclipse)

I`m trying with this code:

```
    android:id="@+id/itm1"
    android:text="item1"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:width="250dip" 
    android:height="150dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image1"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"/>
```

Comment: Prevously asked [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610280/how-to-get-multi-line-text-on-a-button-in-android

Comment: As Lukas mentioned, it's been asked before and the answers on the other question should help you.  You may also want to double-check your width & height properties.

Answer (score 4):

To insert multiple lines in a button, you might use the string.xml to insert the end of line.

1 Create a new variable with the character endOfLine "\n" in the res/values/strings.xml.
For example:

> ```
> <string name="multiplelines">Line1 \n Line2</string>
> ```

2 Refer it in the layout file. For example, for a button:

> ```
> <Button
>     android:id="@+id/start"
>     android:text="@string/multiplelines"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent">
> </Button>
> ```

Source: http://www.jiahaoliuliu.com/2011/10/android-multiple-lines-for-layout.html

Answer (score 3):

It is a little late, but you can also specify number of lines in the Button itself:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:lines="2">

</Button>
```